# how to call two functions with or without wrapping arrow function

Tags: reactjs, onsubmit

```
import{useState } from 'react'

export const useForm=(callback, initialState={})=>{
     
    const [values, setvalues] = useState(initialState)
    const onChange=(event)=>{
        setvalues({...values,[event.target.name]:event.target.value})
    }
    const onSubmit=  event =>{
        callback();
    }
    return{
        onChange,
        onSubmit,
        values
    }
}
 function createPostCallback(){
            createPost();
          }
          const [open, setOpen] =useState(false)
      
        return (
            <Modal 
            as={Form}
            onSubmit={onSubmit}
```

- *this works fine but when i change this to {onSubmit&&setOpen(false)} it says too many renders, so i wrapped an arrow function like this
  {()=> {onsubmit()&&setOpen(false)}} but only the onSubmit function
  works and if i changed it to {()=> {setOpen(false)&&onSubmit()}} only
  setOpen works..what am i doing here how to solve this !!*

  ```
       open={true}
       dimmer={'blurring'}
       onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
       onOpen={() => setOpen(true)}
       open={open}
       trigger={<i  class="circular add icon" ></i>}
     >
       <div>


    <Image size='medium' src='/images/avatar/large/rachel.png' wrapped />
      <TextArea
      rows={2}
       placeholder="whats on ur mind..?"
       name="body"
       onChange={onChange}
       value={values.body}
      >
      </TextArea><Modal.Actions>
      <Button  type="submit" color="instagram">post</Button>
        </Modal.Actions>
       </div>    
       </Modal>
   )
  ```

  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the clean code i would recommend for you to do another function that call both functions:

```
function onSubmitAndSetOpenFalse() {
   onSubmit();
   setOpen(false);
}

...
onSubmit={onSubmitAndSetOpenFalse}
```

or you can do like Shri Hari told

```
onSubmit={() => {  onSubmit(); setOpen(false);  }}
```

Both will work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to call the function without the `&&` operator.

```
onSubmit={() => {  onSubmit(); setOpen(false);  }}
```

Hope that works!